# MVC 5 Ajax.BeginForm POST does not bind to model in conroller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ajax.beginform

Sorry for the amount of code here but it's the best way to explain what;s happening.

I gave this code in my MVC 5 partial view:

```cs
@model Hide.MVC.MFC.Models.RequestDataModel
using (Ajax.BeginForm("RequestSetCanceledState", "Home", null,
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "request-info",
    OnBegin = "AjaxAbsoluteLoaderOn",
    OnComplete = "AjaxAbsoluteLoaderOff"
}, new { id = "formCancel" }))
{   
    <input id="sbmtCancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CancelReason, new SelectList(Model.CancelReasons, "Id", "Name", Model.CancelReason), String.Empty)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Reason)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RequestId)
}
```

My controller action is as follows:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult RequestSetCanceledState(RequestDataModel model)
{
    ...
    return PartialView("....", model);
}
```

And my model is as follows:

```cs
public class RequestDataModel
{   
    public RequestDataModel() { }

    public RequestDataModel(int requestId)
    {
        this.RequestId = requestId;
        using (var service = new InnerServiceClient())
        {
            var request = service.GetRequest(requestId);
            this.State = request.ServiceState;
            if (request.PremiseInformationId.HasValue)
            {
                this.PremisInformation = service.GetExistingData(requestId) ?? new PremiseInformationBL();
            }
        }
    }

    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public int State { get; set; }

    public PremiseInformationBL PremisInformation { get; set; }
    public int? CancelReason { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public List<ListItem> CancelReasons
    {
        get
        {
            using (var service = new DictionaryServiceClient())
            {
                return service.GetShortList(TypeDictionary.MFCCancelReason).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code does post to the RequestSetCanceledState method, and browser send message

```cs
CancelReason=1&Reason=123&RequestId=48&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
```

but the model is always empty. Also, if I use a **GET** request, the **model is not empty**! I tried to remove PremisInformation and CancelReasons from the model, but it did not help. Can someone please tell me why this might be?

Comment: have you included jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js file???

Comment: To my regret, there are no errors in the console. Controller returns a PartialView without problems

Comment: so what is the problem then...???

Comment: POST request does not bind data to model in conroller. At this point `public PartialViewResult RequestSetCanceledState(RequestDataModel model)` model is empty